# SwiftUI: why when I create new View and add it inside HStack in Scroll view it animates by default

Tags: animation, scrollview, swiftui

I have a problem that when I create new View as new View component

```
MyTabView: View { .... }
```

and then place it in

```
ScrollView {  HStack { MyTabView() } }
```

Then it by defaults animate on drag or other changes when I use `withAnimation() { }`

If I create this MyTabView using factory method in its super view like

```
ContainerView { 

    func makeMyTabView() -> some View { }
}
```

then scrolling works ok, and it doesn't have default animation which is messing up which normal horizontal tabs scrolling.

Comment: Did you try to set .animation(nil) on the "MyTabView" ?

Comment: can you add more code to your question, also it would be great to show what kind of animation is happening when you perform drag or other changes.

Comment: I add later more code, animation(nil) did not happen. Generally if I am creating some View in function then it scrolls and slides normally (there is drag gesture attached with onDragEnd withAnimation offset setting. But when I use MyTabView() list then while scrolling there is opacity transition-like animation. I add more code later if I have access to this code